# Cannot turn off XSS filter in Chrome

Tags: xss, chrome

I am using the following command to launch Chrome:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --args --disable-web-security
```

to turn off XSS auditor in chrome in Windows 7, but failed to do so. Below is the screenshot, and any help is appreciated!

[image: browser screenshot including console error]

Comment: Try `--disable-xss-auditor` instead.

Comment: @RobW Tried, work on version 38.x, but not 42.x...Are they making it not working? curiously

Comment: http://www.frameloss.org/2011/11/01/using-google-chrome-for-security-testing/

Answer (score 2):

I am fairly sure your answer lies in the error message.

> The auditor was enabled as the server sent neither an 'X-XSS-Protection' nor 'Content-Security-Policy' header.

I guess Google wants you to be super-duper sure that you want to allow XSS. Try running a local server that returns either of these headers:

- X-XSS-Protection
- Content-Security-Policy

This can be pretty annoying if you are trying to do a simple demonstration using a locally created file, but it is in our best interest, I guess. It may be that Firefox/IE are worth a shot if you just want to see/show how XSS works, but don't want to set up an http server.

EDIT: also make sure you close all instances of chrome when you run a command line.